# Struts 2 JUnit plugin + Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts2, junit, struts2-s2hibernate, struts2-junit-plugin

I'm testing my Struts 2 web application using Struts 2 JUnit plugin, following [Unit Testing](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/unit-testing.html).

In my web application I use `fullHibernateCore-plugin-1.4` to integrate Hibernate functionality.

When I test an action that do some Hibernate stuff, it returns `NullPointerException`.

From what I've understood, since Struts 2 JUnit plugin use a fake container to execute actions, the `HibernateSession` don't get fired.

How can I solve this problem?

This is a test example:

```
public class testRegisterAction extends StrutsTestCase {

    public void testGetActionProxy() throws Exception {
        //set parameters before calling getActionProxy
        request.setParameter("user.name", "TestName");
        
        ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/userRegister.action");
        assertNotNull(proxy);

        RegistrationAction action = (RegistrationAction) proxy.getAction();
        assertNotNull(action);
        
}
```

Comment: Unit tests shouldn't include the DB layer; are you not mocking your services?

Comment: Generally I want to test that my actions do what they should do. In this example RegistrationAction write on a DB a new user.

Comment: That's an integration test, because you're testing multiple things. A unit test would check the action against known behavior of your user service, which would be mocked/stubbed to simulate all/most possible conditions the service could exhibit.

Comment: There is DBUnit, which is designed for such testing. Use of an in memory database is strongly recommended to keep tests agile. As Dave mentioned DB testing is a form of integration testing and generally shouldn't be done with JUnit and DBUnit despite the name it is an integration test... but the name is cool.

Comment: Instead of editing your question, add the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't an Hibernate error, but one concerning Struts Tiles plugin. I was using Tiles and I didn't set `proxy.setExecuteResult(false)`, so JUnit was trying to execute all jsp/tiles stuff (after the action return) giving error. In the stacktrace there were also Hibernate errors and so I thought (wrongly) that the fault was of Hibernate stuff.

I solved setting `proxy.setExecuteResult(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by upgrading to version 2.2.2 generally available on the site [full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2](http://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2/).

<sub>With the version are you using the transaction interceptor is unable to put the session on the stack.</sub>

Comment: No, it works also with 1.4. I thought it was an Hibernate problem, but it wasn't! The problem was caused by Struts Tiles plugin, so now it's ok.

Comment: @MrMoog Ok, describe your problem in the question or in the answer, doesn't matter, I didn't see how the tiles has been concern.